# How can I model a database such that a given entity is extensible?

Tags: sql, database-design, entity-relationship

I'm in the process of designing a database structure for an application that I wish to develop, and I'm stuck wondering how I can design an Entity (I'm using Chen's notation) such that it can be extended by the end user through the program interface.

For example, the software I plan to write is a recipe book/nutritional information manager and I have designated a separate table for the nutritional information of an ingredient. As it stands, I have outlined a few basic attributes, namely Sodium, Carbs, Calories, and Fat. Without going into massive amounts of detail and trying to add every single possible relevant measurement, I'd like the user to be able to add their own things of importance to the database, such as maybe Vitamin A or Iron. I don't know much about database modeling yet (I'm only recently learning how to do it in school) so I presume that I wouldn't want the program to alter the table so that I add new attributes to this entity. So how should I go about doing it?

My (rather incomplete) model thus far follows. There's obviously much more that needs to go in here yet (not to mention the relationships between these entities).

[image]

Comment: http://martinfowler.com/bliki/UserDefinedField.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this particular application I would model it as below:

Ingredients are the basic things you need to make a recipe.

```
ingredients
    id              unsigned int(P)
    name            varchar(15)
    ...

+----+-----------+-----+
| id | name      | ... |
+----+-----------+-----+
|  1 | Flour     | ... |
|  2 | Olive oil | ... |
| .. | ......... | ... |
+----+-----------+-----+
```

Now you have to define what nutrients are found in each of your ingredients.

```
ingredients_nutrients
    id              unsigned int(P)
    ingredient_id   unsigned int(F ingredients.id)
    nutrient_id     unsigned int(F nutrients.id)
    grams           double

+----+---------------+-------------+-------+
| id | ingredient_id | nutrient_id | grams |
+----+---------------+-------------+-------+
|  1 |             1 |           1 |   3.0 |
|  2 |             1 |           2 |  15.3 |
|  3 |             2 |           3 |  20.0 |
| .. | ............. | ........... | ..... |
+----+---------------+-------------+-------+
```

Define all the possible nutrients (do some searching on the USDA website and you can find a complete list). It's trivial to add a records to this table.

```
nutrients
    id              unsigned int(P)
    name            varchar(15)
    ...

+----+--------+-----+
| id | name   | ... |
+----+--------+-----+
|  1 | Sodium | ... |
|  2 | Iron   | ... |
|  3 | Fat    | ... |
| .. | ...... | ... |
+----+--------+-----+
```

Define your recipes.

```
recipes
    id              unsigned int(P)
    name            varchar(50)
    ...

+----+-------+-----+
| id | name  | ... |
+----+-------+-----+
|  1 | Pizza | ... |
| .. | ..... | ... |
+----+-------+-----+
```

Indicate what ingredients go into each recipe.

```
recipes_ingredients
    id                  unsigned int(P)
    recipe_id           unsigned int(F recipes.id)
    ingredient_id       unsigned int(F ingredients.id)

+----+-----------+---------------+
| id | recipe_id | ingredient_id |
+----+-----------+---------------+
|  1 |         1 |             1 |
|  2 |         1 |             2 |
| .. | ......... | ............. |
+----+-----------+---------------+
```

Comment: This is great. Just the type of thing I was looking for, but somehow couldn't visualize it myself.

Comment: It's a good foundation to start with. You'll need to add some things and possibly modify it to work exactly the way you want but this is very similar to the model I used when I wrote some software to track the food/nutrients I was eating.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your additional properties are in the same units, you can do it with a couple of extra tables.

```
table custom_field
-----------------
id
name

table ingredient_custom_field
----------------------------
id
ingredient_id
custom_field_id
custom_value
```

This assumes that the custom fields belong to ingredients. If all your values are in milligrams, then it makes it relatively simple to roll them up for a given recipe- well, simple until you start trying to convert fluid ounces to weight but that's another issue. 
If you were using postgresql, you could use json, hstore, or another data type to store this complex information in the table itself. 
Now, if you wind up having some of the types that are numeric, others that are flags (gluten free,etc.), then you will have to change the design somewhat or make everything store as text, but it'll be more difficult to sum the numeric results.

Answer (score 1):

User-extensible data models may be required, but they are fundamentally not *relational*.

You might be interested in my presentation, [Extensible Data Modeling with MySQL](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/extensible-data-modeling) (though the concepts apply to any RDBMS). Here's the abstract:

> Designing an extensible, flexible schema that supports user
>   customization is a common requirement, but it's easy to paint yourself
>   into a corner.
>
> Examples of extensible database requirements: 
>   - A database that allows users to declare new fields on demand. 
>   - Or an e-commerce catalog with many products, each with distinct attributes. 
>   - Or a content management platform that supports extensions for custom data.
>
> The solutions we use to meet these requirements is overly complex and
>   the performance is terrible. How should we find the right balance
>   between schema and schemaless database design?
>
> I'll briefly cover the disadvantages of Entity-Attribute-Value (EAV),
>   a problematic design that's an example of the antipattern called the
>   Inner-Platform Effect, That is, modeling an attribute-management
>   system on top of the RDBMS architecture, which already provides
>   attributes through columns, data types, and constraints.
>
> Then we'll discuss the pros and cons of alternative data modeling
>   patterns, with respect to developer productivity, data integrity,
>   storage efficiency and query performance, and ease of extensibility.
>
> - Class Table Inheritance
> - Serialized BLOB
> - Inverted Indexing

---

Re your comment:

The answer from @JoeLove is the Entity-Attribute-Value design. I have written others answers about the pitfalls of EAV, or you can read my blog about it, [EAV FAIL](http://karwin.blogspot.com/2009/05/eav-fail.html).

The answer from @BennyHill is the best solution, because it works within the relational database paradigm and doesn't require you to make an "extensible" database schema.

The concept is called a **many-to-many relationship**, for example, a recipe has many ingredients, and in turn each ingredient may be used in many recipes. The relational solution for this is to create a table to represent this relationship, such that you insert one row for each pairing of a recipe and one of its ingredients.

Comment: Interesting... but what is inherently flawed about the above two solutions from Joe and Benny? They're the type of solution I was looking for, but couldn't come up with.